# State/Province ("Region") Required field shipping checkout! MAGENTO2

Tags: magento2, checkout, customer

i want to checkout shipping adress, State/Province ("Region") be Required.

[image]

Comment: > You can set it requried from admin panel. Go to customer configuration and set the preffered fields to required. I couldn't find this on Magento 2.2.5

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/138659)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/138659)

Answer (score 6):

Go to `Stores > Configuration > General` and in `State Options` group mark all countries for which you wish to require State/Province in `State is Required for` field.

Comment: Hello, I did this but it only set state required in profile page but not in checkout page.

Answer (score -1):

You can set it requried from admin panel. Go to customer configuration and set the preffered fields to required.

Else

you can also manually add a "required" class in your .phtml template file.

Please check it and let me know.

Comment: Same problem on Magento2.1 here; cannot find this field in Customer's config in Admin; what's the .phtml file you are referring to?

Comment: @davideghz I have not

Comment: Are you on 2.1? I can't find the field you mentioned

Comment: How to set checkout fields from customer configuration ?